# Microsoft Professional Plus 2010 Installer (with outside programs)

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office

When opening non-Office programs, I get the Microsoft Professional Plus 2010 Installer coming up and wanting to install. I click cancel and it usually comes up again. If I continue to click cancel, eventually it will go away and the program will open. This is happening with programs like Digitrace, Skymate, Waypoint for Windows, and many others, but doesn't happen with any of my Office 2010 products. How can I stop this?

Comment: This usually means there's some unmet dependency. Have you looked at the Event Viewer to see what is being installed? Have you performed a repair install of Office? Have you checked for any MSI issues?

Comment: The reason it "keeps coming back" is due to the fact you are canceling the installation of required files.  You should allow the installer to fix the problem.

Comment: Please go to this location: **C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\Office Setup\ Controller**please rename the file **SETUP.exe**